# http://www.example.com addresses fail, example.com succeeds - apache/route53

Tags: apache-2.4, amazon-route53

This one is really weird.
I've got an Apache web server running on Ubuntu 14.04 with DNS provided by AWS's Route53. When I point a browser (or CURL in a console) to example.com with the http://www in front, the request fails. CURL returns

> curl: (6) Could not resolve host: www.example.com

But when I point the same browsers/consoles to example.com, everything works perfectly. 
/var/log/apache2/error.log reports nothing. Restarting Apache didn't help.
As far as I can see, my DNS record set is fine.
Any ideas?

Comment: Did you set up a record for the `www` subdomain? Give us the domain and the records you have in place.

Comment: No I didn't. There's just the A record pointing to the IP address. Full addresses were working fine a couple of days ago (as far as I remember). I'll tried adding a new A record for www.mysite

Comment: `www.example.com` and `example.com` are totally separate FQDNs and have their own separate records.

Comment: Doesn't really matter. You can make both records be `A` records, or you could `CNAME` www at non-www. Both are fine, the `CNAME` will save you having to change both records if your IP changes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it fails to exhibit the minimum level of professionalism and research required for ServerFault.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: www.example.com`

You need to create a DNS `A` or `CNAME` record for `www.example.com`.

Comment: Thanks! You and ceejayoz were bang on. I can't imagine how I didn't notice this until now...